# Toggle class after removing all instances of class

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my drop-down menu, when user clicks on button, it adds a class to show the drop down list.

So first, it moves all instances of the class. My navigation have several buttons, so removing the class will close other *opened* lists.

Code:

```
jQuery(".nav-js-trigger").each(function(){
    this.onclick = function() {
        // remove all instances of .show-nav
        jQuery('.show-nav').removeClass('show-nav');

        // show list
        jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass( "show-nav" );
    }
});
```

Works fine. Only problem is that there is no way for the user to close the list, because:

1. It removes all instances of class first.
2. **toggles** the class, which will always add the class because it just removed all instances...

How can I toggle the menu on click properly and still remove all instances of the class? Obviously, I need to change my approach.

Comment: Can you produce a demo of the issue?

Comment: Why not just addClass("show-nav") instead of toggle?

Comment: @SamTyson I want to remove the class if user clicks on it again...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hasClass` to detect the state before removing all the classes:

```
jQuery(".nav-js-trigger").each(function(){
    this.onclick = function() {
        var hasClass;
        hasClass = jQuery(this).parent().hasClass( "show-nav" );
        // remove all instances of .show-nav
        jQuery('.show-nav').removeClass('show-nav');

        // show or toggle list
        if (hasClass === false) {
            jQuery(this).parent().addClass( "show-nav" );
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Just drop the current element from your first selection using `not`:

```
jQuery(".nav-js-trigger").on('click', function(){
        // remove all instances of .show-nav
        jQuery('.show-nav').not(this.parentNode).removeClass('show-nav');

        // show list
        jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass( "show-nav" );
    }
});
```

note: I've also cleaned up the way you are binding the click handler, as the `each/onClick` is awkward.

Comment: @Halcyon I did mean the parent, but you don't need to wrap it.

Comment: My clickhandler is required for some mobile browsers believe it or not.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson indeed I do not believe it; for mobile you do `on('click touchstart/touchend')` or use a lib like Fastclick to fake a proper click event.